# Condition in SQL server based on first table column value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in SQL Queries..

I have 2 database DB1 & DB2.

DB1 Contains the table A which has Name,Address & Code columns & DB2 contains the table B which has column Name1,Address1.

if the Code is not null then i want to select Name,Address from the tableA else name1 & address1 should come from tableB.

Please Help me on this.

```
  select top 1
  a.name 'MyName',
  a.address 'MyAddress'
  from DB1.table1 a
  where a.code <> null
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Comment: What the relationship between the tables? I.e. do records share a common id? Is you struggle with the "if null" stuff or with the fact that tables are in different databases?

Comment: @Luftwaffe : I have tried simple query as below but i am not sure how to apply condition on DB2.                                         select top 1
      a.name 'MyName',
      a.address 'MyAddress'
      from DB1.table1 a
      where a.code <> null

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming your tableA and TableB have primary key as "Name"**

```
select 
case when a.Code is not null then a.Name else b.Name end as Name
,case when a.Code is not null then a.Address else b.Address end as Address
from DB1..tableA a
left join DB1..tableB b on a.Name=b.name
```

OR

```
select 
case when isnull(a.Code,'')<>'' then a.Name else b.Name end as Name
,case when isnull(a.Code,'')<>'' then a.Address else b.Address end as Address
from DB1..tableA a
left join DB1..tableB b on a.Name=b.name
```

Comment: We are using join DB1..tableB b on a.Name=b.name but in my case i want only data based on condition of code.

Comment: @user1721131: that's what this does. Though maybe you want the join to go the other way or even be an inner join depending on if the related records are always in A, B, or both. As for this answer, I think IS NOT NULL much better than ISNULL(a.code,'')<>''.

Answer (score 0):

this might also work incase there is no relation between table a and table b.

```
select distinct(code),name, address from (
select 
case when t1.code IS NULL 
then t2.code else t1.code end as code, 
 case when t1.code IS NULL then t2.name else t1.name end as name, 
case when t1.code IS NULL then t2.address else
t1.address 
end address
from t1, t2) t;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/769a4/14)

Where you could replace t1 and t2 with the tables from db1 and db2.